# How to set height of a div element to another div in Angular 9?

Tags: angular

I have two div elements and I want to set the height of first div to the the second div element. I have not specified the height of first div as it grows or shrinks dynamically. I want to get that height and assign it to the second div. Please help me. I tried using the code to get the height of the first div ,

html

```html
<div id"firstdiv" #myIdentifier>
    <p>This is test.</p>
</div>
<div id="seconddiv">
    &nbsp;
</div>
```

ts

```js
ngAfterViewInit() {
    let height = this.myIdentifier.nativeElement.offsetHeight;
   
    console.log('Height: ' + height);
  }
  
  @ViewChild('myIdentifier')
  myIdentifier: ElementRef;
```

This code shows error in IDE that, nativeElement isn't known property of ElementRef. And in browser console it says -

> ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined.

Comment: I have copy pasted your code and everything works fine https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-6pzurd?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: just add this to second div `[style.height.px]='myIdentifier.offsetHeight'`

Comment: That's correct thanks RK001